# How to display a result of query in to a label in a windows application?

Tags: c#, windows

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string costring = connection();
            string MyQuery = "select SUM(balance) from dbo.KmtAccounts where registernumber='" + txtRegNo.Text + "'";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(costring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(MyQuery, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            lblResult.Text = 
        }
```

Comment: This feels like a homework problem cut-and-pasted as a question.

Comment: its working now. private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string costring = connection();
            string MyQuery = "select SUM(balance) from dbo.KmtAccounts where registernumber='" + txtRegNo.Text + "'";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(costring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(MyQuery, conn);
            conn.Open();
            lblResult.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance I would probably recomend that you use [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)  seeing as you have a single value that is returned.

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

Then you would probably look at [Convert.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  when you wish to assign it to the label text property.

Or if you wish to have it formatted, you could look at using [Convert.ToDouble Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx)  and then [Double.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tostring.aspx)  to format it if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string costring = connection();
                string MyQuery = "select SUM(balance) from dbo.KmtAccounts where     registernumber='" + txtRegNo.Text + "'";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(costring);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(MyQuery, conn);
                conn.Open();
                lblResult.Text =cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                conn.close()
            }
```